# how to GET and store specific values as a list from JSON data(URL) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried several approches and none of them works. I think this is because I am using JSON returned by django DRF.
I want to create a list of IFSC using this JSON in Jquery in my HTML template itself.
This is how my api returns JSON for any queryset.

```
{
  "count": 134,
  "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bankdetailapi/?limit=5&offset=5&q=ABHY",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "ifsc": "ABHY0065001",
      "bank": {
        "name": "ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED",
        "id": 60
      },
      "branch": "RTGS-HO",
      "address": "ABHYUDAYA BANK BLDG., B.NO.71, NEHRU NAGAR, KURLA (E), MUMBAI-400024",
      "city": "MUMBAI",
      "district": "GREATER MUMBAI",
      "state": "MAHARASHTRA"
    },
    {
      "ifsc": "ABHY0065002",
      "bank": {
        "name": "ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED",
        "id": 60
      },
      "branch": "ABHYUDAYA NAGAR",
      "address": "ABHYUDAYA EDUCATION SOCIETY, OPP. BLDG. NO. 18, ABHYUDAYA NAGAR, KALACHOWKY, MUMBAI - 400033",
      "city": "MUMBAI",
      "district": "GREATER MUMBAI",
      "state": "MAHARASHTRA"
    },
    {
      "ifsc": "ABHY0065003",
      "bank": {
        "name": "ABHYUDAYA COOPERATIVE BANK LIMITED",
        "id": 60
      },
      "branch": "BAIL BAZAR",
      "address": "KMSPM'S SCHOOL, WADIA ESTATE, BAIL BAZAR-KURLA(W), MUMBAI-400070",
      "city": "MUMBAI",
      "district": "GREATER MUMBAI",
      "state": "MAHARASHTRA"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            var value = $('#q').val()
            $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bankdetailapi/?q="+ value, function(data){
                var text = `IFSC: ${data.ifsc}`
                })
)}
```

It throws error in browser console that `Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined` . I want to use this IFSC list as autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: you can't skip `results` property of `data`, and the fact that `data.results` is an Array ... so, `data.results[0].ifsc` `data.results[1].ifsc` and `data.results[2].ifsc` ?

Comment: Given your own example, `ifsc` is not at the root level, it's inside `results`

Comment: though ... why you'd get `text is not defined` is a mystery - there's absolutely NO reference to any variable or property called `text` in the code you posted

Comment: *other language, not for Jquery* - jquery isn't a language - it's *a fast* (very debatable), *small, and feature-rich JavaScript library*

Comment: Your code, as provided, would give `text` === `"IFSC: undefined"`.   Please read [mcve] - we can't reproduce your issue if you give us different code

Comment: my apologies for calling Jquery as language.  i wanted to say I didnt ind any solution in Jquery.

Comment: in console log 5 json objects are returned , when i run the getJson @freedomn-m

Comment: Please read: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: What's the actual problem?  (other than some terminology).   Are you looking for the [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) statement to loop through your `results`?

Comment: yes. i want to loop through results to get IFSC values

Comment: `for (var i=0;i<data.results.length;++i) { console.log(data.results[i]; })`  Yes, there's "better" ways, but "get the values" is pretty vague - do you want them in array?  A concatenated string?  one by one?

Comment: i dont know how i exactly want them. I am using autocomplete widget. For that i want to pass list of IFSC values

Comment: Its array that i want

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: so i can create a list by using PUSH method. i will get back once i implemented this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       $("#q").keyup(function(){
        var value = $('#q').val()
        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bankdetailapi/?q="+ value, function(data){
        var text = ['']
        for (var i=0;i<data.results.length;++i){text.push(data.results[i].ifsc)}
        // var text = `IFSC: ${data.results.ifsc}`

        console.log(text)
```

By using push method and iterating on whole data i managed to get list of all IFSC values.

Comment: Always better to code it yourself than be spoon fed.   Can be just `var text=[];` to initialise the array.   You can also use `var text = data.results.map(x=>x.ifsc)` for some shorthand.

Comment: i am not comfortable with map. but i guess i have to start working on it. thanks again @freedomn-m

Comment: That's one of the reasons I suggested the `for` + `push` loop (first).   `map` is shorthand for your `for` loop and array generation.  It allows you to convert (or "map") from one format (an array with multiple properties) to an other format (an array with a single property) nice and easily.   Build up your skills bit by bit and understand them as you go, rather than dive in and get confused :)